# np.meshgrid for high dimensional matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create new matrices using `np.meshgrid`, converting matrix like `seq.shape = (a,b,c)` into `pairwise_matrix.shape = (a,b,b,c,3)` where last dimension in the new pairwise matrix is a concatenation of `vi`,`(vi+vj)/2` and `vj` (`vi`,`vj` from `seq`). But it seems that `np.meshgrid` does not work with high dimensional matrices. Is there any other operator can make this happen?

Comment: I'm not following what you are trying to do.  I see some code clips, but no call to `meshgrid` or use of its output.  `meshgrid` takes `*xi`, any number of 1d arrays (upto 32).  Show us exactly how `meshgrid` fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to broadcast your input like so:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a, b, c = 2, 3, 4
>>> seq = np.arange(a*b*c).reshape(a, b, c)
>>> 
>>> weight = np.linspace(0, 1, 3)
>>> result = seq[..., None, :, None] * weight + seq[:, None, ..., None] * weight[::-1]
>>> result.shape
(2, 3, 3, 4, 3)

>>> result
array([[[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
          [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
          [ 3.,  3.,  3.]],

         [[ 4.,  2.,  0.],
          [ 5.,  3.,  1.],
          [ 6.,  4.,  2.],
          [ 7.,  5.,  3.]],

         [[ 8.,  4.,  0.],
          [ 9.,  5.,  1.],
          [10.,  6.,  2.],
          [11.,  7.,  3.]]],

         ...

        [[[12., 16., 20.],
          [13., 17., 21.],
          [14., 18., 22.],
          [15., 19., 23.]],

         [[16., 18., 20.],
          [17., 19., 21.],
          [18., 20., 22.],
          [19., 21., 23.]],

         [[20., 20., 20.],
          [21., 21., 21.],
          [22., 22., 22.],
          [23., 23., 23.]]]]])
```